# How to pass complex params into controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4

This is just my 2nd week on ASP.NET MVC

Basically I have a model called T_Users, in the view page I created a textbox for creating a new record into the database, below is the code:

```
<th scope="row" class="spec">Row</th>
<th scope="col" class ="nobg">@Html.TextBoxFor(A => A.Username)</th>
<th scope="col" class ="nobg">@Html.PasswordFor(p => p.Password)</th>
...
```

How can the controller behind it can get the values? Obviously pass by /xx/xx/ID is not a efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you post the form to a Action, depending on the method of that form you will get the values in a collection.
For example:

HTML

```
<form action="SubmitAction" method="POST">
    <...>
    <th scope="row" class="spec">Row</th>
    <th scope="col" class ="nobg">@Html.TextBoxFor(A => A.Username)</th>
    <th scope="col" class ="nobg">@Html.PasswordFor(p => p.Password)</th>
    <.../>
```

Code Behind

```
 [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult SubmitAction(UserInfo user)
            {
                var value1 = user.Username;
                var value2 = user.Password;
                ...

                ... return something ...
            }
```

and the model

```
class UserInfo
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That helps!
A very small question, in that <form>, I didn't see a standard submit button from @html, what tag should I use to submit the form?

Comment: <input type="submit" value="Send Form" />, anywhere inside the form

Comment: a very quick question: how can I make it as regular html text between to razor markup tag? for example: \@Html.str hello \@Html.str2 How can I make "hello" as html output?

Comment: <text>...your text here </text>

Comment: Thanks! will save me a lot =]

Answer (score 0):

create a model class to represent your record:

```
class UserInfo
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password{ get; set; }
}
```

Now create a HttpPost action Save that accepts your UserInfo class as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Userinfo info)
{
    //info should contain your username and password
}
```

Make sure that the Property names in your class match exactly the name in you html form.